# ActionScript: How to Re- setInterval Each Time Function Works?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript

I have a function that draws a rectangle on the screen (see createInfoPanel())
While drawing rectangle, I am adding 2 text fields on it.
But as you may guess, it is adding those immediately.
I want to delay adding these text fields, then I want to remove these panels after a while.
The problem is, when I set an interval or timer, they won't work after I using once (I had to stop them by clearing/removing, it didn't set them again).
Since my panel is being created each time image changes, I need them to work every time image changes.

So, I have 2 questions:
1- How can I re-set interval each time my createInfoPanel() function works? It won't work anymore after setting and claring once.

2- You can see infoPanel.addChild(titleField); line in addInfoPanel() function. How can I work a smooth animation here? I mean, text appears slowly?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class ImageRotator extends Sprite
{
private var ... ; //Some variables

public function ImageRotator(xmlPath:String = "images.xml", interval:int = 8301):void
{
    timer = new Timer(interval);
    loadXML(xmlPath);
}

private function loadXML(file:String):void
{
    urlLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(file));
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseXML);
}

private function parseXML(e:Event):void
{
    xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    loadImages();
}

private function loadImages():void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < xml.children().length(); i++)
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.load(new URLRequest(xml.children()[i].@src));
        imagesVector.push(loader);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sortImages);
    }
}

private function sortImages(e:Event):void
{
    imagesCounter++;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < imagesVector.length; i++)
    {
        imagesVector.reverse();
        addChild(imagesVector[i]);
    }

    //I have only 3 images, I needed to set indexes because
    //they were covering each other
    this.setChildIndex(imagesVector[2], 0);
    this.setChildIndex(imagesVector[1], 0);
    this.setChildIndex(imagesVector[0], 0);

    if (imagesCounter == imagesVector.length)
    {
        createInfoPanel();
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, autoChange);
        timer.start();
    }

}

private function createInfoPanel():void
{
    infoPanel.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0.0);
    infoPanel.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 967, 138);
    infoPanel.graphics.endFill();

////Here I want to run addInfoPanel() function with 2 seconds delay,
////After it starts, I want to run removeInfoPanel() function with 2 more seconds delay

    addChild(infoPanel);

}

private function addInfoPanel():void {
    titleField.text = xml.children()[infoCounter]. @ title;
    titleField.x = 425;
    titleField.y = 0;

    description.text = xml.children()[infoCounter]. @ description;
    description.x = 427;
    description.y = 26;

    infoPanel.y = 300;
    infoPanel.addChild(titleField);
    infoPanel.addChild(description);
}

private function removeInfoPanel():void {

    infoPanel.removeChild(titleField);
    infoPanel.removeChild(description);
}

private function addActions():void
{
    //Some function
}

private function changeImage(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //Image changing function
}

private function changeDepth(e:TweenEvent):void
{
    //Some function
}

private function autoChange(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    //Some function
}
}
```

Edit: How I used to work the intervals:

```
private function createInfoPanel():void
{
    //lines above code sample
    intervalInfoPanel = setInterval(addInfoPanel,2000);

    addChild(infoPanel);
}

private function addInfoPanel():void {
    //lines above code sample
    clearInterval(intervalInfoPanel);
    intervalInfoPanelRemove = setInterval(removeInfoPanel,3500);
}

private function removeInfoPanel():void {
    //lines above code sample
    clearInterval(intervalInfoPanelRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- How can I re-set interval each time my createInfoPanel() function
>   works? It won't work anymore after setting and claring once.

how exactly are you resetting your interval? you don't show the code here.
but normally you can reset + re-use a timer like this:

```
timer.reset();
```

this will stop and reset the timer's `currentCount` to 0.
you can then later say `timer.start();` and everything should work like it never ran before.

> 2- You can see infoPanel.addChild(titleField); line in addInfoPanel()
>   function. How can I work a smooth animation here? I mean, text appears
>   slowly?

use a tween. add the TextFields with `txt.alpha = 0;` and then tween the alpha value slowly to 1.0. TweenLite (http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) is a great tweening-engine.

```
import com.greensock.*;

txt.alpha = 0.0;
TweenLite.to(txt, 1, {alpha:1.0, delay:0.4});
```

Comment: my fault, I need to reset like this: clear/remove and work again. because if I reset, it will work again no matter if I want or don't. I want to stop it completely, then start again in createInfoPanel() function. when I clear, it won't work again.

Comment: dear @pkyeck, i added the code sample shows how i worked intervals before. as you can see, i clear them in order to deny working again, but i set them again in createInfoPanel() each time, the problem is they won't work after clearing once.

Comment: `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` got nothing to do with the `Timer` class. why do you use two different approaches? you can make a `Timer` only run once if that's what you need. `new Timer(1000, 1);`

Comment: okay, but i tried same way with timer. the problem is that i need timer to delay my text appear. your code only works a timer, how will it delay my text appear?

Comment: for this i'd recommend using TweenLite: http://www.greensock.com/get-started-tweening/

Comment: i'm looking now, do you know any function name for what i want? i mean, delay appear?

Comment: you can just use the snippet i posted in my original answer: `txt.alpha = 0.0; TweenLite.to(txt, 1, {alpha:1.0, delay:0.4});` it tweens the txt's alpha from 0.0 to 1.0 with a delay of 0.4s.